# PHP PDF parser whitespaces in words

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-parsing

I'm using this [PDFParser](http://www.pdfparser.org/) for parsing a PDF file. Suddenly one of file was parsed with whitespaces in words, for example there should be

> Monday

, but it was parsed as

> Mond ay

or

> chicken

as

> chic ken

When I select a text from pdf reader and copy somewhere else, there are not these strange whitespaces. Is there a bug in the library or there are some hidden chars in pdf. How it can be repaired?

EDIT: There is a [link](http://www.restaurace-lihovar.cz/soubory-ve-skladu/pdf/T%C3%BDdenn%C3%AD%20menu-06-2016.pdf) to weekly menu. This PDF file is in czech language, so there is for example word

> Pondě lí

which should be:

> Pondělí

or

> Kuř ecí

should be:

> Kuřecí

I can see all these whitespaces are around character with accents but not always.

I warn you, that it may change after this week and the new menu could be without these whitespaces.

Comment: Can you post the PDF on a public server and add a link into your question? That way we can at the very least confirm or refute if there is something weird inside these strings in the PDF; and that, in turn, could help zooming in on a possible problem in your library.

Comment: Link and next notes added. I used english words first because of better understandability.